# Parsing JSON with VBA-Web and VBA JSON Parser

Tags: json, vba, woocommerce-rest-api

Need help on parsing JSON data using VBA-Web tool (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) & VBA-JSON Converter
Here is my sample code that I am able to pull the order using the get method but I stumped on parsing the JSON to get the key, value pair that I want

```
Sub TestWC()

Dim WoocommerceClient As New WebClient
Dim Client As String
Dim Secret As String


WoocommerceClient.BaseUrl = "https://www.example.com"
    Client = "ck"
    Secret = "cs"
    
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Request.Method = Httpget
Request.AddQuerystringParam "consumer_key", Client
Request.AddQuerystringParam "consumer_secret", Secret
Dim Response As WebResponse
Request.Resource = "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"



Set Response = WoocommerceClient.Execute(Request)

//Response.Data -> Should be equal to the JSON data 

Dim test As Object
Set test = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Response.Data)

End Sub
```

When I run this code it will have a error popup saying object required 424 . I also did another work around where I put into the first cell the whole JSON Data using Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Response.Content then by pulling the data from the cell into the function

`Set test = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)`

I still get the object required error, here is a Sample JSON format from Woocommerce REST API

````
 "id": 727,
  "parent_id": 0,
  "number": "727",
  "order_key": "wc_order_58d2d042d1d",
  "created_via": "rest-api",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "status": "processing",
  "currency": "USD",
  "date_created": "2017-03-22T16:28:02",
  "date_created_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:02",
  "date_modified": "2017-03-22T16:28:08",
  "date_modified_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:08",
  "discount_total": "0.00",
  "discount_tax": "0.00",
  "shipping_total": "10.00",
  "shipping_tax": "0.00",
  "cart_tax": "1.35",
  "total": "29.35",
  "total_tax": "1.35",
  "prices_include_tax": false,
  "customer_id": 0,
  "customer_ip_address": "",
  "customer_user_agent": "",
  "customer_note": "",
  "billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "payment_method": "bacs",
  "payment_method_title": "Direct Bank Transfer",
  "transaction_id": "",
  "date_paid": "2017-03-22T16:28:08",
  "date_paid_gmt": "2017-03-22T19:28:08",
  "date_completed": null,
  "date_completed_gmt": null,
  "cart_hash": "",
  "meta_data": [
    {
      "id": 13106,
      "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
      "value": "yes"
    }
  ],
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 315,
      "name": "Woo Single #1",
      "product_id": 93,
      "variation_id": 0,
      "quantity": 2,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "6.00",
      "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
      "total": "6.00",
      "total_tax": "0.45",
      "taxes": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "total": "0.45",
          "subtotal": "0.45"
        }
      ],
      "meta_data": [],
      "sku": "",
      "price": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 316,
      "name": "Ship Your Idea &ndash; Color: Black, Size: M Test",
      "product_id": 22,
      "variation_id": 23,
      "quantity": 1,
      "tax_class": "",
      "subtotal": "12.00",
      "subtotal_tax": "0.90",
      "total": "12.00",
      "total_tax": "0.90",
      "taxes": [
        {
          "id": 75,
          "total": "0.9",
          "subtotal": "0.9"
        }
      ],
      "meta_data": [
        {
          "id": 2095,
          "key": "pa_color",
          "value": "black"
        },
        {
          "id": 2096,
          "key": "size",
          "value": "M Test"
        }
      ],
      "sku": "Bar3",
      "price": 12
    }
  ],
  "tax_lines": [
    {
      "id": 318,
      "rate_code": "US-CA-STATE TAX",
      "rate_id": 75,
      "label": "State Tax",
      "compound": false,
      "tax_total": "1.35",
      "shipping_tax_total": "0.00",
      "meta_data": []
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "id": 317,
      "method_title": "Flat Rate",
      "method_id": "flat_rate",
      "total": "10.00",
      "total_tax": "0.00",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data": []
    }
  ],
  "fee_lines": [],
  "coupon_lines": [],
  "refunds": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/727"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: Just to be sure - The missing `{` is a typo?

Comment: Yeah the missing bracket is just a typo, forgot to copy the whole thing from the woocommerce rest api

Comment: Did you check the output of `Response.Data` that it's a proper JSON string? and which line did error 424 occured?

Comment: Line occured at the test = JsonConverter.Parsejson(Response.Data). How do I test if the output of Response.Data is Json? And if it isn't what should I do going forward

Comment: @user20157961 I don't use VBA-Web but from the documentation, try `Debug.Print Response.Content` and see what comes out, if its too long then perhaps write to a text file and inspect the output.

Comment: `Response.Data` is *already parsed* to JSON, so you don't need to use `Set test = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Response.Data)` - you can just do `Set test = Response.Data`  Check the examples here: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: Ok so If I do that, how would I go on about getting key/value pairs from the test variable?